# Doctrine2, using 2 tables in 1 entity

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, entities

I'm looking for a way to use multiple tables (One-to-one) in one Doctrine 2 Entity class. Can this be achieved using plain annotations? Adding more classes is not something what I want to do.

I have the following table structure:

```
Attribute:
    id
    type_id
    value
AttributeType:
    id
    name
    unit
```

What I would like to do is create an entity which can basically call getters and setters for the 2 tables from the same class, without having to create separate entity classes, e.g.:

```
<?php
class Attribute {
    public function getName(){ return $this->name; } // From AttributeType
    public function getValue(){ return $this->value; } // From Attribute
}
?>
```

Any help is greatly appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
/**
 * @OneToOne(targetEntity="AttributeType")
 * @JoinColumn(name="type_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
```

Refer [`Docmentation`](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-onetoone) for more details

Comment: Nope, sorry. That'll require me to create an AttributeType entity class. I want to combine the 2 tables into one single entity, without having to write 2 separate classes.